# how ignore warnings to go in stderr

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I'm run a command and I want to just get errors in ‍‍‍‍`stderr` file not warnings

```
➜  ~ pip2 install 0wned 2> error.txt 

Collecting 0wned
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/fb/af45132a70fa67b7a40383066e284182ae649ce5c2a7839c06da51641a43/0wned-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: 0wned

➜  ~ cat error.txt 

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/0wned-0.6.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I want to just get errors in `error.txt`,not warnings.

I want this output:

```
➜  ~ cat error.txt

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/0wned-0.6.0.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: Maybe `grep '^ERROR:' error.txt`?

Comment: it's not always like that, warning can come after error msg, and i think its a dirty way :X i can't understand why warnings should come into stderr!

Comment: You are reading too much into names.  `stderr`'s purpose is to provide an alternative output channel for information other than programs' actual results, so that `stdout` is clean of informative and diagnostic messages.  The distinction between error messages, warning messages, and diagnostics of other kinds is pretty much arbitrary, and `stderr` is the right place for all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the stderr if you want:

```
 pip2 install 0wned 2> >( grep ERROR > only-errors.txt)
```

Explanation:

```
 2> >( command )
```

Redirect the `stderr` stream to `command`

```
grepv ERROR > only-errors.txt
```

Copies lines containing `ERROR` to only-errors.txt file

---

If you want to keep a copy of all error messages, you can add `tee`:

```
 pip2 install 0wned 2> >( tee all.txt |  grep ERROR > only-errors.txt)
```